# 'ImportError: No module named decorator' in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have added a validators library to my google app engine by manually adding the code to a folder `lib/validators`. Then in my code I added this line

```
from validators.utils import ValidationFailure
```

When I run my app I got an exception from this line:

```
    from validators.utils import ValidationFailure
  File "lib/validators/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .between import between
  File "lib/validators/between.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .utils import validator
  File "lib/validators/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
ImportError: No module named decorator
```

If I run `from decorator import decorator` in the python intrepretor, it works as expected.

However when I tried it in the 'interactive console' in the local development server, I got the same error

[image]

How can I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to copy the `decorator.py` and its dependency `six.py` into the same 'lib' folder.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I have  2 simbolic links of this python files in the lib folder, but I doesn't have the original decorator.py, I make a reinstall from source and it works, see my answer

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me, I installed the decorator package specifically for Python 3.4:

```
sudo python3.4 -m pip install decorator  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Comment: Google app engine only supports python up to version 2.7. You also cannot deploy dependency to GAE which is installed via pip.

Answer (score 0):

For *python3* or above, use

```
sudo apt-get install python3-decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `anaconda`, the best approach is to install it through `conda install decorator`.

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

I create the symbolic links like previous answer said, but doesn't work for me.
I have to download the source package

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator#downloads

and I have reinstalled it manually "$ python setup.py install"

And It worked